# EntityFramework 6 AddOrUpdate not working with compound or composite primary key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

The issue has been my weekend nightmare... I have a table where `AddOrUpdate` is not working correctly, it keeps adding but never updating.

All I want to do is when I add a new entity to the table using `AddOrUpdate` I want it to check the `AppointmentId` and `CompletionCodeId` columns and if they match than update, otherwise add.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppointmentCodes] (
    [Id]               INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AppointmentId]    INT NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]         INT NOT NULL,
    [CompletionCodeId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AppointmentCodes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC, [AppointmentId] ASC));
```

^^ Not sure if that is even correct.

```
public void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
{
    //uses DbContextExtensions to check value of primary key
    _context.AddOrUpdate(entity);
    Commit();
}
```

METHOD

```
public void AddAppointmentCodes(List<AppointmentCode> appointmentCodes)
{
    appointmentCodes.ForEach(x => _appointmentCodeRepository.AddOrUpdate(x));
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You missed [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) of `AddOrUpdate`:

```
_context.AppointmentCodes
        .AddOrUpdate(a => new { a.AppointmentId, a.CompletionCodeId },
                     appointmentCodes.ToArray());
```

Comment: Won't work if either of those properties are nullable intergers - or it might if someone could show me how

Comment: Also, doesn't work if you are using Base entity class fields