# Entity Framework - UPSERT on unique indexes

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, upsert

I searched a bit regarding my problem but can't find anything that really to help.

So my problem/dilema stays like this:
I know that mysql database have a unique index system that can be used for insert/update in same query using this format:
`insert into t(a,b,c) values(1,1,1) on duplicate keys update b=values(b),c=values(c);`
and a replace format used to replace a existing recording by that index.

to be honest the only similar stuff that I saw in MSSQL is the `merge` but I really don't like it at all and verifying a query to insert or update isn't unique index based after all...

So how can I emulate the mysql unique UPSERT into Entity Framework? this is my main problem...

I mean without getting the record from entity set and checking it if is null or not for a possible insert or update;

Can I get it? Or not? Any hint can be useful

I saw [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx) but doesn't appear into version 6...

example of entity:

```
    [Table("boats")]
    public class Boat
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(15)]
        [Index("IX_ProviderBoat",1,IsUnique=true)]
        public string provider_code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_ProviderBoat", 3, IsUnique = true)]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string model { get; set; }
        [Index("IX_ProviderBoat", 2, IsUnique = true)]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        [Key]
        public string boat_code { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int built { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }            
    }
```

So I want to update/insert based on the my IX_ProviderBoat unique index using EF

[image]

Comment: Your data model isn't ideal for EF. Do you need to have a `Boat.id` as well as three unique keys in your `boats` table? Why not use the `Boat.provider_code` as your primary key? Also, `AddOrUpdate()` is available in EF6.

Comment: AddOrUpdate is available in EntityFramework6. May be you have to check with other overloads like mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287852/entityframework-6-addorupdate-not-working-with-compound-or-composite-primary-key

Comment: @wahwahwah 1) id is just a identifier(not a primary key); 2) AddOrUpdate is not visisble on my 6.0.0.0 EF Version; 3) provider_code is primary key and also unique index part group;

Comment: Ok - why do you have an 'id' column then? It seems superfluous, but whatever floats your.. boat :)? The `AddOrUpdate()` method is a memeber of `IDBSet`... I'll post an answer.

Comment: @HellBaby - If you are going to include an ID column like that, then the pattern would be to use it as the primary key as a surrogate for the natural key (the unique index), so you dont have to FK as many columns, and so a natural key can be updated without requiring cascades

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `AddOrUpdate` method is a member of `IDBSet` and is available in EF6.

**The `AddOrUpdate` method is not an atomic operation, calls from multiple threads does not guarantee the second thread `Update` instead of `Add`ing again - so you can get duplicate records stored.**

This example was tested and worked to your expectations:

```
        Boat boat = new Boat // nullable fields omitted for brevity 
        {
            boat_code = "HelloWorld",
            id = 1,
            name = "Fast Boat",
            built = 1,
            length = 100
        };

        using (BoatContext context = new BoatContext()) // or whatever your context is
        {
            context.Set<Boat>().AddOrUpdate(boat); // <-- IDBSet!!!
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If we change `boat_code` the `AddOrUpdate()` method will add a new record. If the `boat_code` is 'HelloWorld` it will update the existing record. I believe this is what you are looking for...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just so you know...this upsert is not threadsafe...as I found in production the other day...>_<

Comment: It depends on how you dispose your context... this method has nothing to do with thread safety. And when i say "nothing to do" i mean, you should be expressly calling the GC at some point in your code unless your using boilerplate EF.

Comment: Two threads, two contexts, same command, same time. Duplicated inserts...lots of fun! I had hoped that EF would use `MERGE` atomically. But it uses a select/insert/update.

Comment: I'm actually not sure at all what you're talking about... Are you saying that the `AddOrUpdate` method opens an additional thread?

Comment: Typically, when one asks for an Upsert, one wants an atomic (and possibly idempotent) method. My issue was that two threads (with different DbContexts) called the `.AddOrUpdate` with the same list at the same time. Without proper indices, I ended up with duplicate entries (if I had proper indices, I would have had exceptions). `SQL Server` supports atomic upserts, using the `MERGE` command. But EF does not use it.

Comment: How are you disposing your context? Isnt this a tangential conversation?

Comment: OMG. This has nothing to do with Disposal. I am not reusing the context. Have you even ever read the source code of EF...I am TELLING YOU `.AddOrUpdate` is NOT thread safe. https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbSetMigrationsExtensions.cs

Comment: I've never had an issue. The MS documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions%28v=vs.103%29.aspx How you are implementing the code I think is causing you problems. Maybe i misread the question, but the thread safety issue has to do with scope... not a 10 line code snippet. Sorry if ive caused you any problems.

Comment: `.AddOrUpdate` is for `Migrations`, hence the namespace. It is meant for the DbInitializer. The initializer is meant to be single threaded. The issue is that `MERGE` does something completely different. My point is for the OP to be careful with it!

Comment: @Aron thankyou much! This answer really needs to notify that this is not an atomic `AddOrUpdate` as you would presume.

Comment: I'm not seeing AddOrUpdate in EF6... what namespace is it in? Is it an extension or a member?

Comment: It's in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.. It is an extension. It is not a member of IDBSet

Comment: I found this example but not sure about safety here either: http://forums.asp.net/t/1889944.aspx

Comment: DbContexts are not threadsafe. You should never access the same DbContext instance from more than one thread. That's a different issue from transactions, where you're concerned with multiple DbContext instances. Wrapping this upsert in a transaction is necessary. It isn't as good as a merge (which itself is [not atomic without `holdlock`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)), but it's all EF gives you.

Comment: @jnm2 He meant two threads and one context each. How on earth that could possibly cause a problem is beyond me though, except EF does something exceptionally retarded.

Comment: @John I'm just trying to make sure people don't mix the concept of thread safety with the concept of transactional safety.

Answer (score 0):

For UPSERT I use [EFCore BulkExtensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-extensions) which produces SQL MERGE statement with **BulkMerge** method. The method is *thread safe* since it produces atomic operation on the DB

```
await context.BulkMergeAsync(customers);
```

The package is here for quite a time and can be used with any version of EFCore